# PHP missing notices

Tags: php

here are some X-files.

Let's check this script: https://admin.laysoft.tk/test.php

We tested it on different machines with different version of PHP.

Let's see this:

```
$tomb = 666; 
var_dump($tomb); 
$a = $tomb['akarmi']; 
var_dump($a);
```

Result of this is:

```
int(666) 
NULL
```

(`$tomb` means array)

As you see, we initialized the `$tomb` as an integer.

Why `$a = $tomb['akarmi'];` does not drop a notice, that no key like this?

**UPDATE**

I've reported it, I am so curious.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74579

**UPDATE2**

Ok, this bug is exists from years. There are a lot of issue about this:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37676

Comment: Check the php.ini file for the machine which isn't giving a notice.  it could be that error reporting is off, or configured to only display fatal errors

Comment: Because you defined $tomb, not as an array. You defined it as the number.

Comment: @gabe3886 as you see, error reporting is on, and display errors is on. As I've sad, we tested it on different machines, and different version of php.

Comment: @TeymurMardaliyerLennon Yes, this is why intresting, why does not it drop a notice, that no key like this.

Comment: Can somebody tells me, why this question downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

Because of PHP's [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) feature, which will implicitly convert between types, depending on how you attempt to access a variable.

The conversion to arrays however is not implemented, not even defined how it should work, as the manual says:

> The behaviour of an automatic conversion to array is currently undefined.

---

As for why it has remained that way through the years ... nobody could really answer that question.

Comment: I see, but later, when it is not integer or boolean but a string, it drops the notice.

Comment: Yes, but strings are a sligthly different story with [string access by character index](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) - that's actually referred to in the same manual note I linked.

Comment: Ok, let's check it from another perspective. `$tomb['akarmi']; ` does not exists. It is not `null`, it does not exists.

Comment: Yes it doesn't. But since the engine doesn't know how to convert integers to arrays in the first place, it has no way of checking if it exists. It's frustrating, I know, but you will not find a better answer - guaranteed.

Comment: _engine doesn't know how to convert integers to arrays_ in this case it is worst. It should be warning like "hey man, what the hell you are talking about?". But no, it says, everything is ok, it is null. This is not true. It mislead me. What if there is a key like this with value `null`?

Comment: Man, I don't disagree with you ... I'm just telling you what the status-quo on the issue is.

Comment: Ok, I see, I just wondering. There are tons of bug report from 2013!!! Unbelivable.

Comment: @vaso123 lol, just wondering how much you paid for your license on php ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg 1 dollar.